# JRE Java-CDC does not support debug mode

Tags: eclipse, oracle

I created an OEPE MAF application but when I try to run or debug it, it fails with

```
JRE Java-CDC does not support debug mode
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a JDK and make it the default to be able to deploy the MAF application. In Eclipse navigate to Windows->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs and register JDK 8 and make it the default.

Hope this helps.
-Raghu